# How to shorten "communications"

Tags: abbreviations

I have to put the word "communications" in a graphic. For design reasons I have to make the word shorter. How can eliminate some letters and make it still understandable, is there any correct way to do that?

(I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: You could write "comm" but that's not guaranteed to be understood. Removing other letters (cmncation??) would only be done in very informal text. Unless the graphic is meant to target teenagers, you might want to consider a design that lets you fit the whole word. Note that if it's a question of width, it's acceptable nowadays to write COMMUN on one line and ICATIONS on the next, no hyphen, in an ad.

Comment: This link https://writingexplained.org/english-abbreviations/communication says "comm." = "communications". But, to a non-native English speaker like me, it is difficult to understand what that means. Since you are talking about graphic, can't you make it in your own way - icon, in-the-round type lettering beneath the icon or something.

Comment: I think you want the abbreviation for "communication". It is easily available on google search.

Comment: The word _comms_ is familiar to me, and I suspect to anybody in IT.

Answer (score 1):

### **Comms**

This is the normal abbreviation for those in the industry.

[image]

[image] [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The request is quite ambiguous, since there is no context provided: what kind of communication are we talking about?

Some shorter versions could be:

- comm
- Tx/Rx (from transmission / reception)
- text
- data
- info
- dialogue
- msg (from message)
- chat